# How to understand extending a regular function with extends in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

```js
function MyObject(v) {
  return new Object(v);
}
class D extends MyObject {
  constructor(v) {
    super(v);
  }
}
console.log(new D(1) instanceof Number); // true
```

How to understand this piece of code?

Comment: I'm not in favor of closing the Q. On the contrary I was looking for an enlightening A. since the OP's use case is very special due to ... `function MyObject(v) { return new Object(v); }` ... returning an objectified version of the passed value `v` ... **and not an instance of `MyObject`.** Thus I'm still curiously waiting for an answer which explains why for ... `class D extends MyObject { constructor(v) { super(v); } }` ... and passing a number value to `new D(1)` the resulting instance satisfies  `new D(1) instanceof Number`. It might be not that obvious as one thinks.

Comment: OK, I am voting to reopen

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript OO is based on [prototypes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object_prototypes).

Before class syntax was added to the language, the standard way to do OO was to define a constructor function and then modify its prototype.

```js
function MyConstructor() {
    this.counter = 0;
}

MyConstructor.prototype.add = function () { this.counter++ };

const a = new MyConstructor();
const b = new MyConstructor();

a.add();
a.add();
b.add();
b.add();
b.add();
b.add();
b.add();

console.log(`A: ${a.counter}     B: ${b.counter}`);
```

We now have class syntax so it is usual to write code in that style, but you can extend a traditional constructor function in the same way as you can extend the function created by the `class` keyword.

---

> Will MyObject be invoked as a constructor by super(v)?

That's trivial to test.

```js
function MyConstructor(value = 0) {
    console.log("This constructor function has been called");
    this.counter = value;
}

MyConstructor.prototype.add = function () { this.counter++ };

class ExtendedFromMyConstructor extends MyConstructor {
  constructor(v) {
    super(v);
  }
}

const a = new ExtendedFromMyConstructor(1);
const b = new ExtendedFromMyConstructor(100);

a.add();
a.add();
b.add();
b.add();
b.add();
b.add();
b.add();

console.log(`A: ${a.counter}     B: ${b.counter}`);
```

---

Peter Seliger, in a comment, wants to know why the result of the original code is an instance of `Number`.

This has nothing to do with the focus of the question as expressed by the title.

If a constructor function returns an object, then that is the object that is operated on (even with `new`).

`new Object(3)` is an instance of `Number`.

(And then if you extend the function, it still returns that Number object).

Comment: Will MyObject be invoked as a constructor by super(v)?

Comment: I don't understand this community. A man with almost 1 million reputation still bothers to answer a question people are trying to close. Are we wrong for downvoting and trying to close it?

Comment: @Wimanicesir True and the significant problem is that they downvote everyone else who does that :-)

Comment: I'm not in favor of closing the Q. On the contrary I was looking for an enlightening A. since the OP's use case is very special due to `function MyObject(v) { return new Object(v); }` returning an objectified version of the passed value `v`. Thus I'm still curiously waiting for an answer which explains why for `class D extends MyObject { constructor(v) { super(v); } }` and passing a number value to `new D(1)` the resulting instance satisfies  `new D(1) instanceof Number`. It might be not that obvious as one thinks. **But the above answer for sure does not provide the correct explanation.**

Comment: @PeterSeliger because Object constructor is basically method that falls back to internal `ToObject` operation, which you can read in ECMAScript Specification: [object constructor](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/fundamental-objects.html#sec-object-constructor), [ToObject abstraction](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/abstract-operations.html#sec-toobject)

Comment: @AdrianKokot ... I know all that (and of cause what has been provided by Quentin with the latest edit as well) ... but an expert's answer has to take every aspect/detail of the OP's question and code into account and reflect it. And all of that was missing.